# List Manager not indexing contacts after CSV import

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-api, exm

I am using EXM, and trying to upload contacts via List Manager.

After uploading csv I found that recipients are still 0 so I opened log file and I found some Exceptions like that and I would like if this issue cause any break down in EXM and how I can solve it:

```
ManagedPoolThread #12 14:03:03 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbSearchUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.XConnect.Client
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient.d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Operations.SearchOperationInvoker.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.SearchHelpers.d__6`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.SearchDefinition`1.d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncSearchHitEnumerator`1.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncEntityQueryProvider.d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncEntityQueryProvider.d__17`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncEntityQueryProvider.d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web.ContactsOperationIndexingState.IsFinished(String syncToken)
   at Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent.CheckIndexing(ListOperation listOperation)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException
Message: A task was canceled.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient.d__9`1.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
Message: A task was canceled.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.d__41.MoveNext()
```

Comment: The issue is with xConnext. If you read the error you pasted, it clearly defines a timeout error occurring with communicating with xConnect. This is not a EXM or List Manager issue. Troubleshooting xConnect is what you are needing to do.

Comment: See this question for https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/17639/246 for more info.

Comment: Also, for validating your xConnect system, check out this answer: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/17213/246

Answer (score 2):

Please check your solr connection with xConnect. Possible cause is contacts are not getting indexed.

I faced a similiar issue but after rebuilding the xdb index in solr its started working fine.

You can use this link to get knowledge around how to rebuild and swap solr indexes.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/rebuild-the-xdb-index-in-solr.html