# VisitorIdentification() is impacting page load time

Tags: performance-optimization

Upgraded from 7.2 to 9.0.2 and experienced pages are loading slow comparatively.

During performance testing used DynaTrace and observed that VisitorIdentification() is taking more than 60% of the time while a page is loading. Analyzing how the Robot Detection is configured.

Did anyone experienced this, What could be the possible root causes for the slowness?

Any inputs/hints are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'd suspect a reference data service connection issue / timeout. See [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17139/xp-scaled-xp1-how-to-validate-installed-application-in-each-server-are-correct/17213#17213) for validating connectivity with xconnect.

Comment: @MarkGibbons we see latest data on Analytics dashboard hence I don't think connectivity with xConnect is a culprit here. But I will cross check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we analyzed further using DynaTrace we figured out that function `GetVPathBuildResult(System.Web.HttpContext, System.Web.VirtualPath, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)` was throwing the exception below:

```
d:\inetpub\wwwroot\SiteName\layouts\System\VisitorIdentification.ascx(8): 
error CS0117: 'Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker' does not contain a definition for 'Visitor'
```

This was alarming for us cause it was looking for `Visitor` rather `Contact`. Then we compared the files related to `VisitorIdentification` under `.\layouts\System\` and figured out that the upgrade process dint replace the latest files for 9.0.2. These were still 7.2 files which were looking for 'Visitor'.

Replaced the files with latest version and time duration for calling that function dropped from 6+ seconds to 0.2 Seconds.