# Clicked event is not tracked in Experience profile contact activity when click at any link in EXM email

Tags: exm, experience-profile

We are trying to track click event in Experience profile in `Activity` tab of contact when we click on EXM campaign email link on CM role and standalone role. However, it is not tracking click event every time.

[image]

Update:
Getting the below error in log file.

```
ManagedPoolThread #0 16:56:10 ERROR Updating campaign data statistics failed for message: 9u7y69b4-jdh3-4877-8411-9513273ca3b1
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Reporting.Datasources.Remote.RemoteReportDataSourceProxy.GetData(ReportDataQuery query)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Reporting.ReportDataProvider.ExecuteQueryWithCache(ReportDataQuery query, ReportDataSource dataSource, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Reporting.ReportDataProvider.GetData(String dataSourceName, ReportDataQuery query, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.ReportDataService.ExecuteQuery(IReportQueryData queryData, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.ReportingService.RunQuery(ReportQuery reportQuery)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.ExperienceAnalytics.Reporting.ReportingClientBase`1.GetRows(String keyRoot, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, Boolean skipCache)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.ExperienceAnalytics.Reporting.ReportingClientBase`1.<GetStatistics>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Services.MessageStatisticsService.GetFromAnalytics(Guid managerRootId, Guid messageId)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Services.MessageStatisticsService.GetFromAnalytics(Guid messageId)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Data.MessageStatisticsProcessor.UpdateFromAnalyticsData(EmailCampaignsData campaign)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Data.MessageStatisticsProcessor.UpdateStatistics(EmailCampaignsData campaign)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Data.MessageStatisticsProcessor.Process(CampaignSearchOptions options)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: Service Host URI is not a valid URI.
Parameter name: serviceHostUrl
Source: Sitecore.Framework.Conditions
   at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.RequiresValidator`1.ThrowExceptionCore(String condition, String additionalMessage, ConstraintViolationType type)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.Throw.ValueShouldBeTrue[T](ConditionValidator`1 validator, String conditionDescription)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.ConfigurationBasedHttpTransportFactory..ctor(String serviceHostUrl, String timeout, BaseLog logger)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.ApiKeyHttpTransportFactory..ctor(String serviceHostUrl, Boolean requireHttps, String connectionStringName, String headerName, String minimalApiKeyLength, String timeout)


ManagedPoolThread #1 16:57:11 ERROR Updating campaign data statistics failed for message: 9u7y69b4-jdh3-4877-8411-9513273ca3b1
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Reporting.Datasources.Remote.RemoteReportDataSourceProxy.GetData(ReportDataQuery query)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Reporting.ReportDataProvider.ExecuteQueryWithCache(ReportDataQuery query, ReportDataSource dataSource, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Reporting.ReportDataProvider.GetData(String dataSourceName, ReportDataQuery query, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.ReportDataService.ExecuteQuery(IReportQueryData queryData, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.ReportingService.RunQuery(ReportQuery reportQuery)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.ExperienceAnalytics.Reporting.ReportingClientBase`1.GetRows(String keyRoot, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, Boolean skipCache)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.ExperienceAnalytics.Reporting.ReportingClientBase`1.<GetStatistics>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Services.MessageStatisticsService.GetFromAnalytics(Guid managerRootId, Guid messageId)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Services.MessageStatisticsService.GetFromAnalytics(Guid messageId)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Data.MessageStatisticsProcessor.UpdateFromAnalyticsData(EmailCampaignsData campaign)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Data.MessageStatisticsProcessor.UpdateStatistics(EmailCampaignsData campaign)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Data.MessageStatisticsProcessor.Process(CampaignSearchOptions options)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: Service Host URI is not a valid URI.
Parameter name: serviceHostUrl
Source: Sitecore.Framework.Conditions
   at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.RequiresValidator`1.ThrowExceptionCore(String condition, String additionalMessage, ConstraintViolationType type)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.Throw.ValueShouldBeTrue[T](ConditionValidator`1 validator, String conditionDescription)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.ConfigurationBasedHttpTransportFactory..ctor(String serviceHostUrl, String timeout, BaseLog logger)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.ApiKeyHttpTransportFactory..ctor(String serviceHostUrl, Boolean requireHttps, String connectionStringName, String headerName, String minimalApiKeyLength, String timeout)
```

Comment: Can you check if the Click Email Link goal is there in Sitecore at path /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Goals/Click Email Link. Also, check if all marketing definitions are deployed.

Comment: @RamanGupta, yes email link goal is present there and everything is deployed

Comment: Is there any link related to goal inside EXM email link?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please ensure that `EXM` is enabled in the Content Delivery server `web.config` and also ensure that the `Processing Engine` wasn't stopped. Another thing would be [verifying xconnect](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17139/xp-scaled-xp1-how-to-validate-installed-application-in-each-server-are-correct/17213#17213) which will track and record all the interaction data (open rate & click rate) and rebuild `xDB index`. In addition to that, check the URI you are included in the email.